# cannot resolve symbol when adding minutes into date time in c#?

Tags: c#

I have issue that I cant solve. I am trying to add minutes and subtract minutes. basically be in that 30 minutes block range. However, in my code below I am trying to get my key value and add 30 minutes but for some reason `AddMinutes` gives an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol AddMinutes.

here is my code:

```
                  var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(barCodeValue);
              var gettingTheName = (string) results.Evaluation.Value;
              TextHeader.text = gettingTheName;
              var qrCodeString = $"https://**************.firebaseio.com/Evaluations/.json?orderBy=\"$key\"&startAt=\"{gettingTheName}\"&limitToFirst=1";
              var matchingsLink = new WebClient().DownloadString(qrCodeString);
              var objs = JObject.Parse(matchingsLink);
              var someId = objs.First.First["Active"].ToString();
              var data = objs[gettingTheName];

              try
               {

                    if (!((bool)data["Active"] == false && (bool)data["Completed"] &&    
                        DateTime.Now < data["ScheduleStartTime"].AddMinutes(30) &&
                        DateTime.Now > data["ScheduleStartTime"].AddMinutes(-30)))
```

Comment: What type is `data["ScheduleStartTime"]`?

Comment: Basically, its my timestamp I am getting from json: `"2019-12-16T20:10:57.649418-08:00"`

Comment: `JObject.Parse` returns a `JObject` which has no idea of the actual object structure in `matchingsLink`. That means that `data["ScheduleStartTime"]` is a standard `object`, which does not have an `AddMinutes` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `AddMinutes()` method to the `JToken` type object. AddMinutes only works with DateTime.

`DateTime.Parse("dateInStringFormat")` will parse the string to DateTime format.. to which you can then add Minutes to.

```
   DateTime.Now < DateTime.Parse(data["ScheduleStartTime"].ToString()).AddMinutes(30) &&
       DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(data["ScheduleStartTime"].StoString()).AddMinutes(-30)))
```

Comment: please mark the post as answered if it resolved your issues

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because `data["ScheduleStartTime"]` is not an instance of `DateTime`, since JSON has no built in representation of dates or times. What is most likely is `data["ScheduleStartTime"]` is an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date represented as a string, in which case you should parse it before comparing it to `DateTime.Now`:

```cs
// ...

var scheduleStartTime = DateTime.Parse(data["ScheduleStartTime"].ToString());

if (!((bool)data["Active"] == false && (bool)data["Completed"] &&    
                        DateTime.Now < scheduleStartTime.AddMinutes(30) &&
                        DateTime.Now > scheduleStartTime.AddMinutes(-30)))

// ...
```